# RewriteRule specific file

Tags: .htaccess

has the following redirect rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html(.*)$ manager.php [L]
```

but I wish that it was not perform to the next file

```
somefile.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kinda vague exactly what you're looking for but if you want to redirect every URL that ends in `.html` to `manager.php` except `somefile.html` use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !somefile\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ manager.php [NC,L]
```

Note, that the dot `.` before `html` should be escaped and that there's no need to capture the file name or path (using `()`). If you're actually expecting URLs that could have `.html` in the middle use

```
RewriteRule ^.*\.html.*$ manager.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition before it to exclude it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !somefile\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*).html(.*)$ manager.php [L]
```